# Image Compression libraries for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, compression, nsimage

OK, this is what I need :

- **Lossy** and/or **Lossless** compression *(all options are going to be considered, although Lossless compression will be favoured)*
- **PNG** and **JPG** files support
- **Cocoa-friendly** code and easy integration

---

I've used **[OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)** in the past but I'm currently looking for an alternative.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at ImageIO framework

Comment: @phix23 ImageIO only allows you to shrink an image, not to compress an image without changing its pixel dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

For lossy PNG compression use [libimagequant](http://pngquant.org/lib) (it will convert RGB/RGBA data to palette+alpha, which is 3 times smaller) combined with lodePNG (which supports palette+alpha format, unlike Cocoa's built-in methods).